# Can I use a shaped bokeh filter with a mobile phone camera?

Tags: filters, bokeh, cameraphones, shaped-bokeh

I have found this interesting way to make pictures
[bokeh filter for camera](http://www.notcot.com/archives/2013/05/laser-challenge-12-bokeh-filte.php)

[image]
[image]

but I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same just using a mobile camera. I have tried to overlap something in front of the camera but it's somehow "too close" to render the same effect..?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the mask would need to be smaller than the lens, and almost directly on it for this to work, but may be wrong.

Comment: The aperture is probably not large enough to do on a phone camera.  You typically need to make a design about 85% the size of your widest aperture.

Comment: You also need pretty good depth of field control.  Something else you won't find on most smart phones.

Comment: I didn't say f/stop I said aperture width. And that f/2.2 on an iPhone is nothing like f/2.8 on a dSLR.

Comment: If you want to try to cut clean shapes that are less than an eighth of an inch across you might be able to pull this off on a phone.

Answer (score 2):

**I just did it, so it's possible.** Huawei P10 plus, f/1.8, 2x optical zoom, 54mm equivalent, ISO 50, macro focus, 2.5m away from the source light. The mask was 2.5mm in size and placed a half inch from the lens.

[image: shaped bokeh]

I used a 2.5mm star-shaped screw driver to make the mask. Then I cut a hole on a soda top and pasted the paper over it.

[image: mask]

Answer (score 1):

> just using a mobile camera

Lucky for us, almost all cameras are mobile (Just a joke). On mobile phone camera, the lens is too small to achive that. I made a quick test on my phone.

But there is a chance that if you use an [telephoto lens](https://www.google.com/search?q=telephoto%20lens%20cell%20phone) on top of your camera you could.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however you can not use the filters pictured above. They would need to be much closer to the diameter of the lens. Also, while that would work, in theory, it is very difficult to get bokeh at all from an iPhone. You would need to focus very close, and be very far away from the "bokehed" lights.

Comment: Could you give an example of someone who has actually done this for a mobile phone camera? It works *in theory*, but do the practical difficulties make it a non-starter in reality?

Comment: It definitely would not work well, but it would work. The bokeh shapes would just be very small.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried a lot and could not see any good result